# How to transpose distinct column values to column names and map other column values to each column name

Tags: sql, transpose

I am using Oracle SQL to transpose a table to the output seen below. From my side, I tried doing pivots and joins, but the output doesnt seem to match. Any help on this would be much appreciated

```
Type | Name
-----+-----------
D    | Aamina
D    | Julia
D    | Priya
P    | Ashley
P    | Belvet
S    | Christeen
S    | Jane
S    | Jenny
A    | Eve
A    | Jennifer
A    | Ketty
A    | Samantha
```

Need this kind output...

```
D      | P      | S         | A
-------+--------+-----------+----------
Aamina | Ashley | Christeen | Eve
Julia  | Belvet | Jane      | Jennifer
Priya  | NULL   | Jenny     | Ketty
NULL   | NULL   | NULL      | Samantha
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when type = 'D' then name end) as d,
       max(case when type = 'P' then name end) as p,
       max(case when type = 'S' then name end) as s,
       max(case when type = 'A' then name end) as a       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks @gordon. This is exactly what i was missing